# Access DOM var from content.js script

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to access a global var (timer) on a webpage using the content.js script via my google chrome extension.
However, everytime it returns undefined, even though I can easily access it via the developer console.

```
var mySocket;
console.log('content.js');

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    switch(request.task){
        case "socketInjection":
            window.setTimeout(
            function(){ console.log(timer);}, 5000);

            break;
    }
  });
```

Im using a setTimeout routine there, to make sure the page has loaded completely (which it should've anyways).

Anyone has a solution?
Thanks in advance, Daniel

Comment: possible duplicate of [Building a Chrome Extension - Inject code in a page using a Content script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9515704/building-a-chrome-extension-inject-code-in-a-page-using-a-content-script)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The extension and the content script both have a different global scope than the page, so if there's something like `timer = 5` in the extension *or* on the page, that isn't visible in the content script.

See

https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts

> However, content scripts have some limitations. They cannot:
>
> - Use variables or functions defined by their extension's pages
> - Use variables or functions defined by web pages or by other content scripts

This answer discusses some options:

[Share in-memory objects in Chrome extension content scripts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25453243/share-in-memory-objects-in-chrome-extension-content-scripts)

Answer (score 0):

I missunderstood the context of content.js

> Content scripts execute in a special environment called an isolated
>   world. They have access to the DOM of the page they are injected into,
>   but not to any JavaScript variables or functions created by the page.
>   It looks to each content script as if there is no other JavaScript
>   executing on the page it is running on. The same is true in reverse:
>   JavaScript running on the page cannot call any functions or access any
>   variables defined by content scripts.
>
> Isolated worlds allow each content script to make changes to its
>   JavaScript environment without worrying about conflicting with the
>   page or with other content scripts. For example, a content script
>   could include JQuery v1 and the page could include JQuery v2, and they
>   wouldn't conflict with each other.
>
> Another important benefit of isolated worlds is that they completely
>   separate the JavaScript on the page from the JavaScript in extensions.
>   This allows us to offer extra functionality to content scripts that
>   should not be accessible from web pages without worrying about web
>   pages accessing it.